# Having natbib.bst accessible on Mac OS X

Tags: bibtex, natbib, mac

While running bibtex I'm getting the following error :

```
I couldn't open style file natbib.bst
```

I guess the problem is that bibtex can't find natbib.bst, how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: There is no `natbib.bst` (at least not since the early 1990s): presumably you want something like `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`.

Comment: Great! Many thanks! It's working perfectly. Should I delete this question ?

Comment: I've duped to another question on the same topic